# Delete records when on specified date ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to ask how I could delete item from the database automatically when current date and time reaches record delete datetime stored in database?

Comment: If you are using sql server, your easiest solution is to set up a scheduled job is sql server

Comment: The [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project may help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've tagged this with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework, I'm not sure if you have access to the underlying database server or not. But if you do, your ASP.NET application isn't the best place to do this. Instead, set up a SQL Server Agent job on the backend server that can run at a specified interval and run a `DELETE` query.

Create a stored procedure something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteOnSchedule
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE [dbo].[Table]
  WHERE [DateTimeToDelete] <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END
```

Then run that procedure on a scheduled basis.

Answer (score 1):

As other users have pointed out doing this with ASP.Net is not ideal. You are much better setting up a job or scheduled task.

That being said I know this isn't always possible so there is another route you could take if you really need to-

There is a description here of how to set it up-
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Essentially you just use cache expiration to trigger code execution. You can simply add your delete logic to the callback to do a periodic purge of old records. This is a hack though so I'd use it as a last resort.

Comment: Nice. Sometimes you have no choice but a hack like this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by create a .NET timer that can check anything you want and run the delete code, for example delete unconfirmed  user after 5 minutes.

```
 public static class DeleteEmployerTimer
{
    static private JobsEntities JobDatabase=new JobsEntities();
    private static Timer threadingTimer;

     public static void StartTimer()
     {
         if (threadingTimer==null)
         {
             //raise timer callback every 5 minutes
             threadingTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(CheckData),
                                       HttpContext.Current, 5 * 60000, 5 * 60000);
         }
    }
    private static void CheckData(object sender)
    {
        MembershipUserCollection AllEmployer = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        foreach (MembershipUser Employer in AllEmployer)
        {
            //your condition to delete records (it can be everything you want date, specific data in config file)
            if(!Employer.IsApproved)
            {
                MeWork.Domain.Database.Employer FindedEmployer = JobDatabase.Employer.Find(Employer.ProviderUserKey);
                JobDatabase.Employer.Remove(FindedEmployer);
                JobDatabase.SaveChanges();
                Membership.DeleteUser(Employer.UserName, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create timer in app start

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         ....
         //Create timer
         DeleteEmployerTimer.StartTimer();

    }
}
```