# Should I use temporary database objects instead of sessions for Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, session, asp.net-web-api, temporary-files

I'm working with MVC and Web API. I'm trying to make a simple food recipe and wants the user to be able to add Ingredients, Instructions and Images. I do this by doing ajax calls to the Web Api and build a temporary Recipe object with the help of sessions.

Now I understand that sessions should be avoided because of RESTful API. Is it better to create a RecipeTemp object with an expiration date och add this to my Context? And then use [stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358576/delete-records-when-on-specified-date-asp-net-mvc) to delete the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of solutions to your problem.
It would be ok to use temp db objects if you want to give a user a possibility to change the same recipe on different devices (or if you want to give a user access to a recipe for a long time). 
For other cases, it's enough to use state on a client (like localStorage).

Comment: Makes sense! localStorage it is! Thanks!